# CSS - Div "background-text" instead of background-image

Tags: css, html

I want my div box to have a "raquo" (») position along the right edge of the div box, inside it, but not part of the hyperlink.

My div box is for a hyper link, here is my CSS

```
.episode-nav .alignright a {
    margin-bottom:7px;
    margin-top:7px;
    width:274px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    background:#2A2A2A;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #1B1B1B;
    float:right;
}
```

What can be done?

Comment: How about using a list instead of a div. This is for a menu right?

Comment: A live example of your HTML and CSS codes would be very beneficial for us to help you out more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to create a menu the correct markup you should use is a list, such as this

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, to actually get the `»` working. There are two ways of doing it. You can either add in an additional `span` with a `»` inside it, and place it inside the anchor or the list, or you could use the CSS `:after` pseudo-element to generate the content for you. Do note that this second method has less browser support and may be controversial. Have a look at the `:after` pseudo-element here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after

Have a look at a demo of both methods in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/aQSVp/

Notice how you use the `content` property to generate the content.

```
#after a:after {
    content: '»';
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @Frank - No, which is why I've provided an alternative. The `:after` method is potentially cleaner because the created element do not get injected into the DOM, unlike the `span` method.

Comment: Well, you are right, it's just that I still have 5 to 7.5% users on IE6 and that is why I recommended background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a little raquo raster image and use it as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want with 'background-text'. If you simply want a link with a >> in front, why don't you just do this inside your div?

```
<span>&raquo;<a href="...">This is a link</a></span>
```

Possibly add "white-space:nowrap" to the span's style.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and already has an answer, but there is a CSS solution to this issue.

Using `:before` on the `li`, it's possible to have a `&raquo;` by using the hexadecimal code for it `\BB`. [Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/5VPja/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>List element 1</li>
    <li>List element 2</li>
    <li>List element 3</li>
    <li>List element 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

li:before
{
    content: '\BB  ';
}
```